# K-means does not plotting correctly

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, k-means

I have a data to made a k-means clustering:

[image]

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
num_clusters = 5
km = KMeans(n_clusters = num_clusters, init="random", max_iter=100, n_init=1)
x=km.fit(X)
print(km.labels_)
```

```
Output:
 [3 0 1 ... 2 0 0]
```

Then i made a plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import seaborn as sns; sns.set() 
plt.scatter(X[:,0],X[:,1], c=km.labels_, cmap='rainbow')
```

But got this result:

[image]

What could be a reason why i got this results?

Comment: The reason is that you plot the race `X[:,0]` vs gender `X[:,1]`, with different color per cluster. Not sure what you mean by 'correctly', but your title is misleading, and what you ask is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're plotting the two first dimensions of X (race and gender) with colors being the clusters found by K-means. There's thus no surprise why you get these results.

I believe what you are looking for is a way to [visually check that the clustering done by K-means makes sense](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2UeU.png). For that, you'll have to visualise all the features used by K-means to make clusters: but that's 41, and our eyes can not see more than 4.

An interesting solution here is [dimension reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensionality_reduction): most of the information in the 41 features can be synthetized into less (e.g. 2). For example using [principal component analysis](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html) (PCA), you can *compress* X into two features. Try the following:

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
X_pca = PCA.fit_transform(X, n_dim=2)
plt.scatter(X_pca[:,0], X_pca[:,1], c=km.labels_, cmap='rainbow')
```